# Getting some problems passing data to another activity

Tags: android

im doing an app on Android Studio.
Here is how my app works. (is suppose to work):
I got 2 activities
On the first one i got  8 CheckBox , and 1 button,
on the second activity i got 8 TextView.

So... I´m trying to get the text from the Checkbox,(if it is Checked) and send it to my second activity (with my button), to the Textviews.

So i want to get the text from my CheckBox on my FirstActivity and send it to my TextView on the second activity.

Everything works fine and perfect, untill the user press the back button on hes phone, if he presse it he goes back to the first activity, and when he tries to do it again i got an error, that my index is out of Exception.

Here is the code: first Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox[] MinhaCheckBox;
    SharedPreferences Dados;
   String MinhaPasta = "Pasta";
    String valor = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btn_Gerar(View v)
    {

        int IDTexBoz[] = {R.id.checkBox,R.id.checkBox2,R.id.checkBox3,R.id.checkBox4,R.id.checkBox5,
                R.id.checkBox6,R.id.checkBox7,R.id.checkBox8};
        MinhaCheckBox = new CheckBox[IDTexBoz.length];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < IDTexBoz.length; i++)
        {
            MinhaCheckBox[i] = (CheckBox)findViewById(IDTexBoz[i]);

        }
        for (int a= 0; a < MinhaCheckBox.length;a++)
        {
            if(MinhaCheckBox[a].isChecked()) {
                valor += MinhaCheckBox[a].getText().toString() + ";";
            }
        }



        Intent segundaTela = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
        segundaTela.putExtra("valor",valor);
        startActivity(segundaTela);
    }
}
```

Second Activity code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
String MinhaPasta = "Pasta";
    TextView[] MeusTextViews ;
    String[] valor ;
    String x = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        int MeusTextVieID[] = {R.id.textView,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.textView4,R.id.textView5,
                R.id.textView6,R.id.textView7,R.id.textView8,};
        MeusTextViews = new TextView[MeusTextVieID.length];

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        x = extras.getString("valor");


            valor  = x.split(";");
            x = "";
            for (int i = 0;i < MeusTextViews.length;i++)
            {
                MeusTextViews[i] = (TextView)findViewById(MeusTextVieID[i]);

            }
            for (int a = 0; a < valor.length;a++)
            {
// here is where i got the error, when trying to do it for the second time(if you had pressed the back button on your phone)
               MeusTextViews[a].setText(valor[a]);
            }




    }


}
```

Here is the error:

```
 Process: com.example.talisson.appsharedpreferences, PID: 5934
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.talisson.appsharedpreferences/com.example.talisson.appsharedpreferences.Main2Activity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8
            at com.example.talisson.appsharedpreferences.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the button again in activity 1 the data is added to the valor variable because it is global. So the valor array is longer than MeusTextViews in the second activity.

Just make the global valor variable in activity 1 local, so its created every time the button is pressed.

Like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox[] MinhaCheckBox;
    SharedPreferences Dados;
    String MinhaPasta = "Pasta";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btn_Gerar(View v)
    {
        String valor = "";
        int IDTexBoz[] = {R.id.checkBox,R.id.checkBox2,R.id.checkBox3,R.id.checkBox4,R.id.checkBox5,
            R.id.checkBox6,R.id.checkBox7,R.id.checkBox8};
        MinhaCheckBox = new CheckBox[IDTexBoz.length];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < IDTexBoz.length; i++)
        {
            MinhaCheckBox[i] = (CheckBox)findViewById(IDTexBoz[i]);
        }
        for (int a= 0; a < MinhaCheckBox.length;a++)
        {
            if(MinhaCheckBox[a].isChecked()) {
                valor += MinhaCheckBox[a].getText().toString() + ";";
            }
        }

        Intent segundaTela = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
        segundaTela.putExtra("valor",valor);
        startActivity(segundaTela);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your main Activity when you are creating the valor you need to do this:

```
    valor = "";
    for (int a= 0; a < MinhaCheckBox.length;a++)
    {
        if(MinhaCheckBox[a].isChecked()) {
                valor += MinhaCheckBox[a].getText().toString() + ";";
        }
    }
    //remove the last semicolon because when you split by ';' in second activity the array size would be one more that what you want. The last value being empty
    if(valor.length()>0){
        valor = valor.substring(0,valor.length()-1);
    }
```

It has nothing to do with the first time or second time. What is happening is second time you probably have all the checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 0):

In first Activity you can do this:

```
... 
valor = "";
for (int a= 0; a < MinhaCheckBox.length;a++)
...
```

You are adding to valor the string values two times and index is greater than the length of the array.

edited:
you can do this on only time in onCreate or calling a function

```
    int IDTexBoz[] = {R.id.checkBox,R.id.checkBox2,R.id.checkBox3,R.id.checkBox4,R.id.checkBox5,
            R.id.checkBox6,R.id.checkBox7,R.id.checkBox8};
    MinhaCheckBox = new CheckBox[IDTexBoz.length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < IDTexBoz.length; i++)
    {
        MinhaCheckBox[i] = (CheckBox)findViewById(IDTexBoz[i]);

    }
```